# How can I load a js file in only one view via Webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker

I have a js file that is specific to one view (people/show), and I don't want to load it on other views. How can I tell webpacker to compile that js only for that particular view?

In application.js I currently have `require('people')`.

Running Rails 6.0.0.rc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any file you put inside the `packs` folder gets compiled, you don't need to tell webpacker to do that. You can then add `javascript_pack_tag "people"` to your view.

Comment: Thank you! That answer also cleared up confusion I was having with the correct way to include custom js modules.